# Auth with flask-socketio

Tags: python, socket.io, jwt, flask-socketio, python-socketio

I want to pass authorization headers from js client to the python code during the socketio connection. I am using `SocketIo-client v.4` and `flask-socketio v.5`.

socketio client connection:

```
socket = io(`${config.apiUrl}/friendship`, {
  autoConnect: true,
  transportOptions: {
    polling: {
      extraHeaders: {"Authorization": "Bearer abc"},
    },
  }
}),
```

sample server python code:

```
class FriendshipNamespace(Namespace):
  def on_connect(self):
    print(request.headers)  # no Authorization key
    print(request.headers.get('Authorization'))  # None
    # join_room(self.room)
```

But I don't know why my backend doesn't receive this `extraHeaders`. What is the correct way to send the access token to the server?

Tell me if you need some additional info. Would be grateful for any help, thank you.

Comment: Inspect the request in your browser's network tab to see if the header was included or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing options in a format that was used in an older version of the socket.io client.

Example from the documentation:

```js
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io({
  extraHeaders: {
    "my-custom-header": "1234"
  }
});
```

See the current documentation for the [extraHeaders](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#extraheaders) option.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful. I figured out the problem, I was trying to send credentials within a namespace, while it must be done in the first socket connection.